# TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm at 128 bytes?

Tags: c#, encryption, tripledes

I'm trying to update my encrypt decrypt function from DES to TripleDES.
However, when I try to increase my key and iv byte array size from 8 to 128:

```
byte[] key = new byte[128], iv = new byte[128];
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
```

Where 8 was used for DESCryptoServiceProvider and 128 is now used for TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider I always get the same error:

```
Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.
```

Even though my byte arrays are complete filled in.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any requirement besides the length to allow my key and iv to be used to create an Encryptor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Key sizes are in **bits** not in bytes. 3DES key size is 168, 112 or 56 bits, depending on [keying option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options). The C# implementation supports key sizes of 128 and 192 **bits**, from which it will only use 112 and 168 bits, respectively.

Comment: Doh, Stupid me. Let's change it :)